# Polar coordinate system : Is radial coordinate is a function of angular coordinate?

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving, polar-coordinates

In polar coordinate system: The polar coordinates $r$ is called the radial coordinate and $\theta$ is called the angular coordinate, often called the polar angle.

I am confused when answering the question that: Is it true that in this case $r$ should be a function of $\theta$ (or Is it possible that $r$ may not be a function of $\theta$, still $(r,\theta)$ represent valid polar co-ordinate system)?

Could anyone please help me to answer this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should it be? In the analogous case with Cartesian coordinates, must $x$ always be a function of $y$?

Comment: Why do you ask? How did you come to think about this question and to be confused by it? Perhaps by knowing that we can figure out why it confuses you and how to resolve the confusion.

Comment: I tried to approximate a self intersecting closed curve by using polar coordinate. So there is a possibility that I can get more than one values of $r$  for a single value of $\theta$. Here I stuck, if it is true that $r$ should always be a function of $\theta$ for polar representation, then approximating such self intersecting closed curve by polar function is not possible .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a set of points in the plane may not be the graph of $r=f(\theta)$ ($r$
as a function of $\theta$) in polar coordinates.
However, it *is* possible for the graph of $r=f(\theta)$ 
to be a self-intersecting curve, for some choices of the function $f$.

More generally, not only is it possible for the graph of $r=f(\theta)$ 
to have points at more than one distance $r$ along a single radial line,
but there are several well-known functions that do exactly that.
For example, if you plot $r = e^{\theta/20}$, you will get a spiral
that wraps around the origin as many times as you want, depending on
the values of $\theta$ that you plot.
Each "wrap" is separated from the ones before and after it, so you can
have a very large number of values of $r$ in the same direction.
The secret is, one point is at $r=f(\theta),$ another is at $r=f(\theta+2\pi),$
another is at $r=f(\theta+4\pi),$ and so forth, because every time you
add $2\pi$ to the polar angle you come back to the same radial line.

You can make a plot of this function [by following this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3Dexp%28theta%2F20%29+for+theta%3D-15+to+15).

That particular function does not create a self-intersecting curve, but 
other functions do. For example, you can plot $r = e^{-(\theta^2)/16}$
by [following this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3Dexp%28-theta%5E2%2F16%29+from+theta%3D-10+to+10).
The plot of this function intersects itself more than once.

This is unlike plots of $y=f(x)$ in Cartesian coordinates, where it is
impossible to plot a self-intersecting curve in that way because
each point has a unique pair of $(x,y)$ coordinates.
Polar coordinates, on the other hand,
allow you to plot the same point in many different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the answer to the question: Is it true that in polar coordinate $r$ should be a function of $\theta$? is yes. Am I right?

Comment: There are many interesting curves that can be described that way. I only hesitate to answer a simple "yes" because you may sometimes encounter curves that must be described differently (for example, parametrically or implicitly). No coordinate system can plot _all_ curves using only equations where one coordinate is a function of the other.

Comment: So your claim is: we can also find some graph of curve in polar coordinate system (not parametrically) for which $r$ may not be function of $\theta$.

Comment: Possibly the simplest example is a straight line through the origin. For example, the line along the $x$-axis has formula $\theta = 0,$ in which $r$ does not even appear.